# A word to express "win by a narrow margin"

Tags: phrase-requests

What is a better way to say
`Team A won by a narrow margin`?
How can I succinctly express that in the end, me and the opponent were `neck to neck`?

Comment: squeaked by: to win by a narrow margin

Comment: Asking for a better way to write something is off-topic writing advice, primarily opinion based, and far too broad to be reasonably answered on a Q&A site of our format.

Answer (score 3):

To  ***[win by a neck](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/win-or-lose-by-a-neck)***

> - to win  any contest by a narrow margin

Collins Dictionary

also:

A ***[narrow](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/narrow) victory*** is an idiomatic expression you can use:

> - narrow victory/defeat/majority/margin etc

Longman Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

The horse racing term for a very close victory is to [***win by a nose***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/win-by-a-nose).

Answer (score 3):

Carrying on with your horse-race analogy,

> Team A won by a nose

[By a nose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by%20a%20nose):

> by a very short distance